# Functional Component not receiving props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to pass post as a props to my Show component with help of onClick event which send that post to clickhandler and then that clickhandler send that post to Show component that i have created. But the problem is that clickhandler function is receiving the post correctly at console.log is working but the component is not receiving as there is only one console.log output on browser developer console.

#### Show component

```
import React from 'react';

const Show = ({post}) => {
   
    console.log(post);
   
        return (
        <div>
            {post}
        </div>
    ) 
    
    
}

export default Show;
```

#### Post Component

```
import Show from './Show'

const Post =({post,setCurrentId}) => {
    
 ...  
 const  handleclick = (post ) => {
     
    console.log(post);

    <Show post={post} />

   }
    return(
     .....

        <Button  onClick={() =>  handleclick(post)} >Show Image</Button> 

     .....    
    );
}
```

what i am trying to achieve is that i want to show that particular post only from list of all post that are rendering .

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite the right paradigm for React. What you'll want to do is set some state to the post you click and then render the `Show` component by returning it if there is a `post` in state. This should start getting you therer, but your individual implementation will surely be slightly different.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Post = ({post,setCurrentId}) => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState();

  const handleclick = (selected) => {
    setPost(selected);
  }

  if (post) {
    return <Show post={post} />;
  }

  return (
      .....
      <Button  onClick={() =>  handleclick(post)} >Show Image</Button> 
      .....    
  );
}
```

Comment: error : Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Hmm, that's not caused by anything in the component that I can see, but there could be something in the `Show` component that's problematic?

Comment: `import React,{useState} from 'react';

const Show = ({post}) => {
   const [newPost , setNewPost] = useState();
   setNewPost(post);
    console.log(newPost);
   
        return (
        <div>
            {newPost}
        </div>
    ) 
    
    
}

export default Show; `

Comment: i just removed the changes in Show component and it works now.  Can you explain me why it was not right paradigm before or at least reference me to some documentation so i can understand  why i needed to set some state to post as you told before.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using state object and basic JS and CSS. Just create states in the constructor of the class Post that contains a flag (eg. isAvailable). If the button is clicked just turn the flag to true. Once the flag is true the Show component is visible with the post passed in the props.

```
import React from 'react';
import Show from './Show';

class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {isAvailable: false};
    }
    const handleClick = (post) => {
        this.setState({isAvailable: true});    
    }
    render()
    {
        if(this.state.isAvailable)
        {
            return {
                <div>
                    <Button onClick={() => {handleClick(post)}}>Show Image</Button>
                    <Show post={this.props.post} />
                </div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return {
                <Button onClick={() => {handleClick(this.props.post)}}>Show Image</Button>
            }
        }
    }
}
```